# php s3 pre signed url without sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using this class to generate a direct upload form which includes the policy part.

https://designedbyaturtle.com/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/

The uploads are working but I want to be able to display the file from the url for users on the site without making the files public.

I understand the SDK has a simple method for this but I am hoping I can do it with the existing code as this already creates the policy. I'm wondering what are hte steps for creating this url from scratch? It seems excessive to include the entire bloated SDK for just one function.

Comment: I'd say you'd want to start at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html and locate the REST API on how to create a signed URL. Whilst your SDK size bloat might be a concern, its autoloading is fantastic and the memory impact should be low.

Comment: The *policy* that is signed for direct uploads is entirely different from the *canonical request* that is signed for pre-signed URLs.  However, there is useful code in that example for constructing the signing key... so this is a helpful start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an S3 pre-signed URL is actually very easy for GET requests. PUT is fairly easy, but POST is complicated and requires a policy.

The challenge is creating the signing code. Amazon supports two versions v2 and v4. v2 is being phased out. v4 is somewhat complicated to code.

If you are only creating pre-signed URLs for GET requests, write your own code. For anything else, I seriously recommend using the SDK.

Below is a link to the source code to pre-sign an S3 URL using S3V4 using PHP without the AWS SDK.

[S3LINK-V4.PHP](https://gist.github.com/kelvinmo/d78be66c4f36415a6b80)

Comment: I solved it by using some functions and making a lightweight class, the API is really bloated.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you bothered. I actually used a modified code based on that one you just posted so you are correct, thanks.

Comment: @xmxmxmx Hi, can you share it, please.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using these two classes and modifying them a bit to make a class with two functions geturl and getform instead of using the API, these work great for v4 signatures.

getform:

https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/

geturl:

https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/4448695ad531016ec12bcdacc9d91cb8

Comment: @UmairHamid: You found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes @ashishmishra

Comment: @ashishmishra Please check my answer in this thread

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function in php using @xmxmxmx answer and it is working fine with me

```
function AWS_S3_PresignDownload($AWSAccessKeyId, $AWSSecretAccessKey, $BucketName, $AWSRegion, $canonical_uri, $expires = 8400)
{
    $encoded_uri = str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($canonical_uri));
    // Specify the hostname for the S3 endpoint
    if ($AWSRegion == 'us-east-1') {
        $hostname = trim($BucketName . ".s3.amazonaws.com");
        $header_string = "host:" . $hostname . "\n";
        $signed_headers_string = "host";
    } else {
        $hostname =  trim($BucketName . ".s3-" . $AWSRegion . ".amazonaws.com");
        $header_string = "host:" . $hostname . "\n";
        $signed_headers_string = "host";
    }

    $currentTime = time();
    $date_text = gmdate('Ymd', $currentTime);

    $time_text = $date_text . 'T' . gmdate('His', $currentTime) . 'Z';
    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
    $scope = $date_text . "/" . $AWSRegion . "/s3/aws4_request";

    $x_amz_params = array(
        'X-Amz-Algorithm' => $algorithm,
        'X-Amz-Credential' => $AWSAccessKeyId . '/' . $scope,
        'X-Amz-Date' => $time_text,
        'X-Amz-SignedHeaders' => $signed_headers_string
    );

    // 'Expires' is the number of seconds until the request becomes invalid
    $x_amz_params['X-Amz-Expires'] = $expires + 30; // 30seocnds are less
    ksort($x_amz_params);

    $query_string = "";
    foreach ($x_amz_params as $key => $value) {
        $query_string .= rawurlencode($key) . '=' . rawurlencode($value) . "&";
    }
    
    $query_string = substr($query_string, 0, -1);

    $canonical_request = "GET\n" . $encoded_uri . "\n" . $query_string . "\n" . $header_string . "\n" . $signed_headers_string . "\nUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD";
    $string_to_sign = $algorithm . "\n" . $time_text . "\n" . $scope . "\n" . hash('sha256', $canonical_request, false);

    $signing_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', hash_hmac('sha256', 's3', hash_hmac('sha256', $AWSRegion, hash_hmac('sha256', $date_text, 'AWS4' . $AWSSecretAccessKey, true), true), true), true);

    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $signing_key);
    return 'https://' . $hostname . $encoded_uri . '?' . $query_string . '&X-Amz-Signature=' . $signature;
}
```

Call it using

```
echo AWS_S3_PresignDownload('accessId', 'seceret', 's3BucketName', 'reGion', '/fileKey.ext', 60);
```