# AWS S3 Authenticating Requests Using Query Parameters to download file with custom name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a signed URL of a file that can let the user download file from the S3 bucket.
I'm following this way written in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).
The generated signature is working perfectly and it gets to download the file as well when a user visits the URL. The problem is that I want the name of the downloaded file to be custom.
For example: FileKey: `tg6AbybBgFMidmKy5dz4vVXZ` FileName: `test.xlsx`

The file is saved on S3 with the key and without the file extension.

So, when a user downloads the file, it's extensionless and hence unrecognized by OS. I want it to be downloaded with the `FileName`. I tried adding `response-content-disposition` in the query but it throws the error:

[image]

Below is the code I'm using right now.

```py
    # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    amz_date = time.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

    # **CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST**
    canonical_uri = '/' + document_key
    canonical_headers = 'host:' + bucket_url + '\n'

    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

    # Create the canonical query string in URL-encoded (space=%20).
    canonical_querystring = 'response-content-disposition=attachment; filename="' + document_name + '"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'' + document_name
    canonical_querystring += '&response-content-type=' + document_type
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + quote_plus(access_key + '/' + credential_scope, safe='')
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + amz_date
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=' + url_expiry
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers

    canonical_request = request_method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers.lower() + '\n' + signed_headers.lower()

    # CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
    string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    
    # CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature
    
    # Merge for downloadable URL
    download_url = 'https://' + bucket_url + canonical_uri +'?' + canonical_querystring
```

**I'm not using AWS SDK. I'm trying to do it on my own!**

EDIT: Even after adding `&` which was missing, I was getting a signature mismatch.

Comment: Check my answer, i have done it using php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862880/php-s3-pre-signed-url-without-sdk/46879021?noredirect=1#comment112990867_46879021 you can use this algo in python

Comment: @UmairHamid, Is that working for custom file name?

Comment: this will gets the file you have to rename that file using server-side logic or client-side logic. I did it using server-side logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with encoding and I missed a `&` in `canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm`! It killed my 3 days looking around all forums and trying different things!
Here's the working piece of code!

```py
  # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    amz_date = time.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

    # **CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST**
    canonical_uri = '/' + document_key
    canonical_headers = 'host:' + bucket_url + '\n'

    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

    # Create the canonical query string in URL-encoded (space=%20).
    canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + quote_plus(access_key + '/' + credential_scope, safe='')
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + amz_date
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=' + url_expiry
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers
    canonical_querystring += '&response-content-disposition=' + quote('attachment; filename=\"' + document_name + '\"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'' + document_name, safe='')
    canonical_querystring += '&response-content-type=' + quote(document_type, safe='')

    canonical_request = request_method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers.lower() + '\n' + signed_headers.lower() + '\n' + 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'

    # CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
    string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature
    
    # Merge for downloadable URL
    download_url = 'https://' + bucket_url + canonical_uri +'?' + canonical_querystring
```

I was using

```py
quote_plus('attachment; filename=\"' + document_name + '\"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'' + document_name,)
```

instead of which I had to use

```py
quote('attachment; filename=\"' + document_name + '\"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'' + document_name, safe='')
```

**Using this method/logic you can generate link of S3 Object with custom filename without using aws-sdk**